# click2mail molpro api Illegal character exception only when in Google App Engine in production

Tags: php, xml, google-app-engine

I'm having a problem with my GAE instance (php55). My app is interacting with the api at http://click2mail.com/ and my code works just fine when I run my GAE on localhost, but click2mail is throwing an error when I run it from my GAE in production. They are producing a large stack trace and the root cause error in the trace is:

```
WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 5))
at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,213]
```

Their api is xml based, so I produce an xml string (of mailing addresses) and POST it to their api endpoint. I've contacted them and provided them with the xml I'm uploading and they can't find anything wrong with it and it uploads for them just fine.

I've done some exhaustive testing today to figure out the problem.

I set up a new Google App Engine instance so that I could isolate it from the rest of my app and try to get a minimal environment. I put together a simple test page so I could run it side-by-side on localhost and in the Google Cloud on GAE.

I verified the error still existed when I tried to upload 3000 addresses in Google's Cloud and still works when I do it from localhost.

Then I split the dataset in two (1500 and 1500) and tried each of them to see if one of them would work. Both worked on local, both failed in Google's Cloud.

I tried splitting it into 4 (750 each). All worked on local. All failed in Google's Cloud.

Then I tried uploading just a single address, the first address. Worked on local, failed on Google's Cloud.

Then I tried uploading a single address again, but the last address (just in case). Worked on local, failed on Google's Cloud.

I've tried to find anything that might be different from localhost GAE to production GAE. The code was using `SimpleXMLElement` to produce the xml and I thought maybe production GAE had a different implementation or something (much like ImageMagick works differently from localhost to production), so I tried updating the code to manually produce the XML instead of using `SimpleXMLElement`. Unfortunately, it worked on localhost but still failed in Google's Cloud.

Something is different about production GAE and is interfering with my app. It doesn't appear to be a problem in my code nor on click2mail's side, so I really need your help.

Here is an example of one of the xml api uploads I did where I only included a single address (but I've changed the address for privacy):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<addressList>
    <addressListName>test list one address time 1489112489</addressListName>
    <addressMappingId>XXXXXX</addressMappingId>
    <addresses>
        <address>
            <seller_id>XXXXXX</seller_id>
            <due_date>2017-03-03</due_date>
            <id>110</id>
            <num>1</num>
            <c_id>34</c_id>
            <title>XXXXXX</title>
            <first_name>XXXXXX</first_name>
            <last_name>XXXXXX</last_name>
            <address>XXXXXX XXXXXX Ave</address>
            <city>XXXXXX</city>
            <state>CA</state>
            <zip>XXXXXX</zip>
            <o1></o1>
            <o2></o2>
            <o3></o3>
            <mail_address>XXXXXX XXXXXX Ave</mail_address>
            <mail_city>XXXXXX</mail_city>
            <mail_state>CA</mail_state>
            <mail_zip>XXXXXX</mail_zip>
            <phone1></phone1>
            <manager_id>1</manager_id>
            <delivery_type_id>8</delivery_type_id>
            <carrier>click2mail</carrier>
            <cost>0.4220</cost>
            <weight>0.0000</weight>
            <offer_exp>Friday, March 24, 2017</offer_exp>
            <mailer_tracking>XXXXXX</mailer_tracking>
        </address>
    </addresses>
</addressList>
```

I even saved the xml to a file in Google Storage, downloaded it, and wrote some Java to check it character by character to see if it had any weird control characters in it. The only ctrl chars in it were linefeeds (`\n`).

As I said, the following code works just fine on localhost GAE, but click2mail throws an exception when I run it in production GAE.

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<addressList/>');
$xml->addChild('addressListName', $listname);
$xml->addChild('addressMappingId', $mappingid);

$addresses = $xml->addChild('addresses');

foreach($addresslistarray as $row) {
    $address = $addresses->addChild('address');

    foreach($fieldnames as $field) {
        $value = '';
        if ($row[$field] != null) {
            $value = htmlspecialchars($row[$field]);
        }
        $address->addChild($field, $value);
    }
}

$xmlstring = $xml->asXML();

$url = c2m_endpoint('addressLists'); // just builds the api url

$response = c2m_httppost($url, $xmlstring);


function c2m_httppost($url, $content) {
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify'=>'ca-bundle.crt']);

    $config = [
        'auth' => [c2m_username(), c2m_password()],
        'body' => $content,
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type'     => 'application/xml',
        ]
    ];

    try {
        $response = $client->request('POST', $url, $config);
        $result = (string)$response->getBody();
        return c2m_xml_to_map($result);

    } catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException $e) {

        error_log("URL: $url");
        error_log("REQUEST: ".GuzzleHttp\Psr7\str($e->getRequest())."\n\n");
        if ($e->hasResponse()) {
            $mesg = "RESPONSE: ".GuzzleHttp\Psr7\str($e->getResponse())."\n\n";
            print($mesg);
            error_log($mesg);
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

I've exhausted all of my ideas. Do you have any ideas why this would work on localhost but fail in production on GAE?